# Buffer Overrun - Can't seem to locate the porblem

Tags: c++, buffer-overrun

I'm trying to locate the problem in this simple example code that produces the "Buffer Overrun Warning", and after looking at it for a while I decided to post this in hope of someone maybe seeing the error in my code?

Message: **Warning C6386** Buffer overrun while writing to 'tmpArray':  the writable size is 'line.public: unsigned int __thiscall std::basic_string,class std::allocator >::length(void) const ()*12*4' bytes, but '52' bytes might be written.

Example that produces the warning:

```
#define STEP 12

void main()
{
    std::string line("Hello!");

    float* tmpArray = new float[line.length() * STEP];

    unsigned int v = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        tmpArray[  v  ]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 1]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 2]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 3]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 4]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 5]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 6]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 7]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 8]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 9]  = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 10] = 0.0f;
        tmpArray[v + 11] = 0.0f;

        v += STEP;
    }

    delete[] tmpArray;
}
```

I don't see where I'm stepping into memory that doesn't belong to tmpArray, I mean the buffer is allocated precisely based on the same values as the string's length and the step-size.

Comment: Looks like a correct program and bogus warning to me. I don't know why the compiler would give this warning, since it's unlikely it can actually predict at compile time either the value of `line.length()` or even whether values of `line.length()` will always be the same on each call. (And if 52 bytes is too many, apparently the compiler suspects the first `line.length()` could be 1, but the next could be greater?) Maybe someone figured the words "might be" mean they can give the warning any time the compiler has no clue if it's safe?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response! That's what I was suspecting as well, because no matter how long and hard I look at it I can't see the problem... I've tried copying the line.length() into an unsigned int and use that in both places, and now the warning is gone... weird...

Comment: If this is the exact code, it could be a compiler bug

Comment: What is your compiler (which version)?

Comment: It's odd that the array size is actually 12 * 5 * 4 = 240 bytes (bytes is mentioned in the error). The array is 12 * 5 = 60 floats, which is still over the number 52 in the error message. Why "52"?

Comment: Also, the compiler really doesn't know the length of `line` at compile time (well, at least it's not a constant).

Comment: Does it give the same warning when you replace `line.length()` with a constant `5` when allocating the array (maybe try with 5 in the for loop as well)?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses; it is the exact code that produces the error, yes. Compiler is the default VS Community 15' compiler. When I copy the value returned by line.length() to a const unsigned int, and then put that uint into both the float array size-allocation and in the for loop, I get no warnings... strange...

Comment: It's actually not that strange I guess. (Well in this case it is, but in the general case, not that much). `line` could grow for any reason after you have allocated `tmpArray` (it could even grow during the loop execution), so it does not seem that stupid from the compiler to warn about the potential risk here. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to aschepler who commented above, the solution to this turned out to be to copy the value returned by .length() into a const unsigned int, and then use that in both places, like so:

```
const unsigned int lineLength = line.length();
```

Allocation:

```
float* tmpArray = new float[lineLength * STEP];
```

For loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
```